# INITCAP in MariaDB

Tags: sql, regex, database, mariadb, constraints

I am currently trying to check that every values that are inserted into my MariaDB table the 1st letter of every word in uppercase, so I tried to use `CONSTRAINT nombreok CHECK (INITCAP(nombre_director) = nombre_director));` but it doesn't works because it gives me an error saying that function INITCAP() cannot be used in a CHECK... what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think `initcap()` is not deterministic because the results may depend on the default collation of the database (under some circumstances).

You can ensure that the first characters are capitalized using:

```
CONSTRAINT nombreok CHECK (not (nombre_director collate latin1_general_cs) REGEXP '(^|[[:space:]])[[:lower:]]')
```

[Here](http://%20%20%20%20CONSTRAINT%20nombreok%20CHECK%20(not%20(nombre_director%20collate%20latin1_general_cs)%20REGEXP%20'(%5E%7C[[:space:]])[[:lower:]]')) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to check the lower case as well:

```
CONSTRAINT nombreok CHECK ((nombre_director collate latin1_general_cs) REGEXP '^([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+([[:space:]]+|$))+$')
```

However, you might want to extend this beyond just alphabetical characters.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=55a06d06743ae48b40ec2c6e80c569f9) is a db<>fiddle for this.

Comment: Have you tried it in mariadb? I think it doesn't work

Comment: And what if I also want to check the uppercase after a "-"?

Comment: Add that into the characters you are looking for.  For a hyphen, I would start the regular expression with  `(^|[[:space:]]|[-])` because hyphen is a special character.

Comment: but I really think that this expresion doesn't work because if you enter 'Abc $ab', it doesn't make an exception... It should be supossed not to let them go in.

Comment: @Trickv2 . . . You should ask a question where you provide all the details of what you are trying to accomplish, along with enough examples to cover the cases the you know about.

Comment: Did it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921871/initcap-constraint-mariadb

Comment: What about Dutch names (van ...), Irish names (O'Br...), two-word names (Smith-Jones), etc?